# AngularJS: Access a dynamic base href value in service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an `index.html` which has a dynamic `base href` value.
`<base href='someDynamicValue'>`
The value changes based on the environment in which the code is deployed.
I need to access this href value in an angular service.How do I get this value using the services provided by angular? Thanks

Comment: so the `someDynamicValue` isn't set and changed by AngularJS? it's changed by the backend or something?

Comment: Its changed by `gulp-replace-plugin` during gulp build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an elegant AngularJS way, use this:

```
$document[0].baseURI;
```

Note: you have to inject [`$document`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document).

Comment: Ok, but I am actually looking for an elegant way to do it. Isn't there something in native angular services like `$location` to get this value?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$scope.base = $document[0].baseURI;
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $document Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document)
- [MDN Web API Reference - Node.baseURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI)
- [MDN `<base>` Element API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$document) {
    $scope.base = $document[0].baseURI;
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  baseURI = {{base}}
</body>
```